# MySQL Full Join with Where clause giving incorrect results

Tags: mysql, outer-join

I am having a problem with getting the correct results from a (pseudo) full join. So I created a sample table to illustrate the problem.  I created a test database (TestDB) with two tables as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `TestDB`.`MyTable` ( `Leg1` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL , `Leg2` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL , `Leg3` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `testdb`.`MyChair` ( `Back1` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL , `Back2` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL , `Back3` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

(:-P) and put some value in there as follows:

MyTable

[image: MyTable]

and MyChair

[image]

Now I use the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `mychair` LEFT JOIN `mytable` ON mytable.Leg1 = mychair.Back1 
UNION
SELECT * FROM `mychair` RIGHT JOIN `mytable` ON mytable.Leg1 = mychair.Back1
WHERE mytable.Leg1 = 'A'
```

This should give me one row, but actually gives me two as if the condition is being ignored (see below).
[image]

Is there some problem with my syntax?

Comment: It's your design. Fix the table structure for`MyTable` to store values tranposed

Comment: @GurV not sure what you  mean. It's a simple structure and should work with any query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do. The last where clause is being used only for right join part, not for whole query. Use this

```
Select * from (
SELECT * FROM `mychair` LEFT JOIN `mytable` ON 
mytable.Leg1 = mychair.Back1 
UNION
SELECT * FROM `mychair` RIGHT JOIN `mytable` ON 
 mytable.Leg1 = mychair.Back1) t
WHERE t.Leg1 = 'A'
```